# HQL joins in Grails

Tags: grails, join, groovy, hql

I have a relationship like this

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bars: Bar, things: Thing]
}

class Bar {
    // Has nothing to tie it back to Foo or anything else of importance
}

class Thing {
    // Has nothing to tie it back to Foo or anything else of importance
}
```

I have an instance of `Thing`.  **I want to get all instances of `Bar` that are associated with all instances of `Foo` that are associated with the instance of `Thing` that I have.**

I have used Grails `executeQuery` method several times but my query does not work.

Here is a working query that will get all instance of `Foo` related to an instance of `Bar`.  I expect the query I need will look very similar, I'm just having trouble with the HQL joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f FROM Foo f INNER JOIN f.bars bars WHERE bars =:bars
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.Bars FROM Foo f inner join f.things thing where thing.Id in (:validThingIds)
```

grails should support setting parameters and you basically need to pass the array of ids to the query.. The final part of the query should evaluate to `(1,2,3,4)` where 1,2,3,4 are the ids of the valid things.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! I figured it out like right after I posted :)  Unfortunately I am now having similar problem with another relationship structure. Care to take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113527/hql-joins-in-grails-part-deux