# HQL joins in Grails: Part Deux

Tags: grails, join, groovy, hql

This is an extension of the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112758/hql-joins-in-grails/11112867#11112867)

I have a relationship like this

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bars: Bar]
}

class Bar {
    // Has nothing to tie it back to Foo or Thing
}

class Thing {
    static hasMany = [bars: Bar]
}
```

I have an instance of `Thing`.  **I want to get all instances of `Foo` that are associated with all instances of `Bar` that are associated with the instance of `Thing` that I have.**

Is what I want possible via HQL (is HQL somehow aware of the indirect relationship between `Thing` and `Foo`)?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a picture of a possible relationship.

[image]

If I had `Thing1` and I wanted all the instance of `Foo` that are indirectly associated with it via `Bar` then the solution I need would return `Foo1` and `Foo2`

Comment: what do you mean by _associated with all instances of bar_?

Comment: @Baz1nga Updated my question with graphical support

Comment: I updated my answer because your question is actually simpler than what it was originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select foo from Foo foo
where not exists (select thingBar.id from Thing thing left join thing.bars thingBar
                  where thing.id = :thingId
                  and thingBar.id not in (select fooBar.id from Foo foo2
                                          left join foo2.bars fooBar
                                          where foo2.id = foo.id))
```

EDIT: Now that you've explained what you wanted with a nice picture, it's simpler. In fact what you want is all the Foos which are linked to **at least one** bar (and not all the bars) also linked to the Thing. The query would thus be:

```
select foo from Foo foo
inner join foo.bars fooBar
where fooBar.id in (select thingBar.id from Thing thing inner join thing.bars thingBar)
```

Comment: Wow that is nasty :)  Is there any thing I can do (a `belongsTo` or some other relationship definition) that would reduce the verbosity of that query?

Comment: This is the best I can do. Maybe something simpler exists, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work ?

```
Foo.withCriteria {
    bars {
        in('id', thing.bars.collect { it.id })
    }
}
```