# Grails / Hibernate criteria id inList

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, criteria

This question is based on the one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113527/hql-joins-in-grails-part-deux).  Same relationships and same goal.  I have an instance of Thing. I want to get all instances of Foo that are associated with all instances of Bar that are associated with the instance of Thing that I have.

I have a method in my model that returns a list of objects based on some criteria.

```
class Foo {

    static List findAllAssociatedWith( Object obj ) {
        def results = null
        if( obj instanceof Bar) {
            results = Foo.withCriteria() {
                bars{
                    //inList( "id", Thing.bars.id ) // this does not work
                    inList( "id", [new Long(3), new Long(4)] ) // this works
                }
            }
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

`Thing.bars.id` returns the list of ids I want to check against, but apparently it is an an ArrayList of Integers even though Longs are expected.  This is the error I get:

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long. Stacktrace follows:
Message: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

**Why is `Thing.bars.id` returning a list of Integers instead of a list of Longs and how do I fix it?**

**UPDATE:**

I found the issue after calling `println Things.bars.id`.  I expected it to return an ArrayList of numbers (Integers or Longs) like this:

```
[3,4]
```

but instead I got an ArrayList of ArrayLists where the first array list was what I wanted and the second array list was an empty list, like this:

```
[ [ 3, 4 ], [] ]
```

Not sure why Grails does this, but an easy way around it for now is `Thing.bars.id.get( 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

ubiquibacon, you can flatten your array of arrays to simple array  by using flatten method
    Thing.bars.id.flatten()

your [ [ 3, 4 ], [] ]  turns into   [3,4]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the definition for `Thing.bars`, it's hard to tell what's going on here.  However, if you have a list of Integers you'd like to turn into Longs, you can use

```
Thing.bars.id*.asType(Long)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I asked a similar question a bit ago and have updated this question with a link back to my previous question which has graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that wonky list because you're not taking advantage of the [spread operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator).

Try this:

```
Thing.bars*.id
```